# How to construct Django enum filter

Tags: django-models, enums

The following is to get 1 record out of database by matching enum type.

```
TYPES = (
    ('ABC_ABC', 'abc abc'),
    ('XYZ_XYZ', 'xyz xyz'),
)


class Hello(models.Model):    
  type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=TYPES, blank=True)
```

database:

```
'1', 'ABC_ABC', 'other data'
```

Queryset:

```
qset = Q(type__in=('ABC_ABC'))
hello = models.Hello.objects.filter(qset)
```

Output:

```
print('count: {}'.format(hello.count()))
```

Result is 0. It should be 1. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your Q filter as follow:

```
qset = Q(type='ABC_ABC')
```

**Explanations:**
When using `in` lookup, django expects an iterable. As you provided only one value, I suspect, it tried to iterate over the string 'ABC_ABC' which is why you didn't get any hit.

If you really want to use the in lookup, which is useless in this case, you should add a comma in to force creating a 1-tuple.

```
qset = Q(type__in=('ABC_ABC',))
```

**Further thoughts**

As this query is quite basic, using a Q object is superfluous. You can simply call

```
.filter(type='ABC_ABC')
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, maybe you could mark it as your chosen answer? ;)